# can not crawler https://www.autorentals.com using python requestes

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I am new to crawler, I have no idea how to get the price data from https://www.autorentals.com using requests

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.autorentals.com/'
data = {
    'l': "LAX",
    'date1': "05/14/2017",
    'date2': "05/17/2017",
    'time1': "10:00",
    'time2': "10:00",
    'type':"checkbox",   
}

html_post = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(html_post.content)
```

The returned content is not the price data I want to get when I click the find deals.

Comment: The html_post.content is full HTML.
Which part you need from html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my post method can not give me the price data,I need to get the price when search for the rental car, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You receive the whole HTML as a text. 
Inside that you have always some parts defining the values you are looking for:

```
<div class="rateCellDiv" id="matrixRate182809314">


                            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.autorentals.com/reserve?rid=182809314&place=matrix_2');return false;"  style="display: block;text-decoration: none;overflow: hidden;" class="arInternalLink">


                        <span class="unitPrice">
                            <span>$34.78</span>
                            <span style="color: #666666; font-size: 60%;font-weight: normal;">/ Day</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="totalPrice" style="color: #666666;">
                            total
                            $155.56
                        </span>

                            </a>

            </div>
```

So you can simply check use the find-method for things to check for

```
"<span class="unitPrice">
                            <span>"
```

Then you search for the end tag of span and you have the value that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how you got the price, I did not get it, are you using the same post code as mine? thanks